# type error :'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

```
from random import randint
random_number = (randint (33, 126))
print (random_number)
print (chr[random_number])
```

i am generating a random number from 33 to 126, and trying to turn that random number into its ASCII equivalent.

However, this error keeps on showing up :TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You cannot iterate over a single random number.  You should do some research on for-loops.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're trying to do is change the random number to a character.  Replace:

```
for i in (random_number):
    print [chr[i]]
```

with this:

```
print [chr[random_number]]
```

Answer (score 0):

`random_number` here is a single integer. A `for` loop needs a range, "from x to y", so one number isn't enough to tell the system what to count. You can use something like `for i in range(33, random_number):`, but from your description, I don't know why you're using a `for` loop at all. Use `print chr(random_number)` instead.

Note the use of parentheses instead of brackets. You should be calling a function here.